# Change column names' dtype from float to string?

Tags: r, string, dtype, r-colnames

I recently got this error while trying to put my data into tensorflow format:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
ValueError: column_name: age vocabulary dtype must be string or integer. dtype: <dtype: 'float64'>.
```

Is there a command that will allow me to change the format of my data frame's column name from a float to a string?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [NLP](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NLP/versions/0.2-0) (Natural Language Processing) package, you can use `as.String(x)` to coerce the column names to a string and then store them again as the column names of the dataframe. This can be done iteratively:

```r
library(NLP)

float_colnames <- colnames(df)

string_colnames <- rep("", length(float_colnames))
for (i in 1:length(float_colnames)) {
  string_colnames[i] <- as.String(test[i])
}

colnames(df) <- string_colnames
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! @Kel Varnsen